# SocketError: sockaddr resolved to multiple nodename

Tags: ruby, getnameinfo

Following snippet failing for ruby, removing of this snippet didn't show any error.
I see closed issue https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/15067 , are they same.
Any input on this snippet will be very useful.

```
platform_is_not :windows do
        describe 'using NI_NUMERICHOST as the flag' do
          it 'returns an Array containing the numeric hostname and service name' do
            Socket.getnameinfo(@addr, Socket::NI_NUMERICHOST).should == [ip_address, 'ftp']
          end
        end
      end
```

with error

```
Socket.getnameinfo using IPv4 using a 3 element Array as the first argument using NI_NUMERICHOST as the flag returns an Array containing the numeric hostname and service name ERROR
SocketError: sockaddr resolved to multiple nodename
/home/travis/build/alpha/ruby/spec/ruby/library/socket/socket/getnameinfo_spec.rb:111:in `getnameinfo'
/home/travis/build/alpha/ruby/spec/ruby/library/socket/socket/getnameinfo_spec.rb:111:in `block (6 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/travis/build/alpha/ruby/spec/ruby/library/socket/socket/getnameinfo_spec.rb:65:in `<top (required)>'
```

Comment: What is the content of the "3 element Array"? (replacing the IP addresses or hostnames if needed)

Comment: ["AF_INET", 21, "localhost"]

Comment: @Addr = ["AF_INET", 21, "localhost"] , Socket::NI_NUMERICHOST=1 ,  ip_address=127.0.0.1

Comment: What's the result of the following code when you run it that host (for ex. with `irb`)?
`require 'socket'; Socket.getnameinfo(["AF_INET",21,"localhost"],Socket::NI_NUMERICHOST)`

Comment: Switch to inspect mode.
require 'socket'; Socket.getnameinfo(["AF_INET",21,"localhost"],Socket::NI_NUMERICHOST)
Traceback (most recent call last):
        5: from /home/travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/bin/irb:23:in `<main>'
        4: from /home/travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/bin/irb:23:in `load'
        3: from /home/travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/irb-1.0.0/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        2: from (irb):1
        1: from (irb):1:in `getnameinfo'
SocketError (sockaddr resolved to multiple nodename)

Comment: Do you have DNS aliases for that IP? DNS load balancing for that hostname?

Comment: cat /etc/hosts
## Managed by Chef on packer-5fe9f627-e9d8-8da5-7235-a54548d5f923.c.eco-emissary-99515.internal :heart_eyes_cat:
## cookbook:: travis_build_environment
##     file:: templates/default/etc/cloud/templates/hosts.tmpl.erb
127.0.1.1 localhost localhost ip4-loopback 
127.0.0.1 localhost nettuno travis vagrant travis-job-381572c2-8a24-4697-9727-73c63c8d8d81

Comment: No dns loadbalancing present.

Comment: Why do you have `127.0.1.1 localhost` and `127.0.0.1 localhost` in your `/etc/hosts` ?? That is the cause of your problem

Comment: I started on new system, its good now.